# Shell script error "filename.json is a directory"

Tags: linux, shell, azure-pipelines

Im using the below shell script in an Azure Devops pipeline as an inline script. The files are there and in correct location. However it is intepreted as a directory? Tried the path with and without quotes...

**Error**:
"sort: read failed: /home/vsts/work/1/s/Oldtemplate/filename.json: Is a directory"

**Code**:

> comm -13 <(sort -u "/home/vsts/work/1/s/Oldtemplate/filename.json") <(sort -u  "/home/vsts/work/1/s/filename.json") > "/home/vsts/work/1/s/SomeFile.txt"

Comment: isn't the reason already in message? e.g. `sort: read failed: /home/vsts/work/1/s/Oldtemplate/filename.json: Is a directory`

Comment: it is possible to have a directory named exactly that.

Comment: check the permissions of the file. unable to read.

Answer (score 0):

So, the file was downloaded through Azcopy withs source = folder, not  file. Filename.json ended up as a directory (with permissions: "drwxrwxrwx"). Fixed the azcopy source and now it works. Thanks all :)